# Android notifications not handled in a FIFO way

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using the [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager) to send notifications via a [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel).

I send multiple (40+) notifications with the same notification ID to show the progress of the operation to the user. I expect that every notification overwrites the last one.

Sometimes (especially in cases where there are 40+ progress updates) the notifications don't seem to be handled in the order in which I sent them, which results in the problem that my "final" success notification gets lost and the last notification is one of the unfinished progress notifications.

I verified that my code sends the notifications in the expected order but I am confused since I did not find anything in the documentation of `NotificationManager` or `NotificationChannel` which indicates in which order (if any) the notifications are handled.

I know that I can work around my main problem by using a different ID for the final success notification but that would still leave the possibility that the progress which is shown to the user is going backwards sometimes...

Am I missing something? Does the documentation state somewhere in which order the notifications are handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after playing with a minimal project that reproduces the problem I figured out what was happening.

There is a notification limit on Android to prevent DOS attacks (makes sense). [This article](https://medium.com/mindorks/the-notification-limit-per-app-in-android-94af69a6862c) explains this quite well. The limit might be 50 notifications (per package) but it depends on the device. My testing device was limited with 25 notifications. I still could not find anything about that in the documentation.

Unfortunately the solution from the article does not work in my particular scenario since I still only have one active notification when I use `setProgress()` on the `NotificationCompat.Builder`. But the solution might work in situations where there are a lot of active notifications that have piled up over a longer period of time.

Even more disillusioning: my initial idea for a work around (see question) does not work either, since a notification will be dropped nonetheless if the limit is reached independent from its notification id.

The problematic code is in `NotificationManagerService`:

```
// Limit the number of toasts that any given package except the android
// package can enqueue.  Prevents DOS attacks and deals with leaks.
                if (!isSystemToast) {
                    int count = 0;
                    final int N = mToastQueue.size();
                    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                         final ToastRecord r = mToastQueue.get(i);
                         if (r.pkg.equals(pkg)) {
                             count++;
                             if (count >= MAX_PACKAGE_NOTIFICATIONS) {
                                 Slog.e(TAG, "Package has already posted " + count
                                        + " toasts. Not showing more. Package=" + pkg);
                                 return;
                             }
                         }
                    }
                }
```

`mToastQueue` is an ArrayList so basically the notifications are handled in a FIFO way, BUT if the queue is full a newer notification will be dropped and the older notifications from the queue will be handled afterwards, which was what gave me the impression that the order was mixed up.

**TL;DR**
If you send notifications fast (especially when using progress updates) there is a risk of losing many of these.

I think I will stop using the determinate progress notifications and just send ONE indeterminate one at the beginning. Or send the important last one after a timeout and accept that the progress updates might be off.